# How can I get Guilds From OAuth2

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made A simple OAuth2 To get Username, ID and Avatar But How can I get User Guilds?

Then I want to Join My Bot To the Guild.
here is my Code:

```js
const guildMembersResponse = fetch(`https://discord.com/api/guilds/@me`,{
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Bot TOKEN",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(guildMembersResponse)
        }, 500);
```

however I an error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://discord.com/api/guilds/@me' from origin 'https://example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
discord.com/api/guilds/@me:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
/#token_type=Bearer&access_token=tokforaccess&expires_in=604800&scope=identify:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Comment: You cannot self join guilds, someone from inside the guild with `MANAGE_SERVER` permissions must do it for you.

Comment: i dont want join how can i get groups just see them

Comment: That's not possible, you can only see mutual guilds.

Comment: yes i mean that i have Let the bot see what servers your in so i can